# How to determine which list elements contains a record in R

Tags: r

If you have a list of vectors, what is a good way of determining which list elements contain a specific record?

```
set.seed(8675309)
aList <- list(v1=sample(LETTERS, 20), 
              v2=sample(LETTERS, 10))
```

The output of aList looks like this:

```
 > aList
$v1
 [1] "E" "L" "S" "R" "F" "O" "T" "Q" "P" "H" "N" "I" "X" "D" "U" "K" "W" "B" "G" "V"

$v2
 [1] "B" "V" "U" "H" "M" "O" "F" "Z" "C" "N"
```

I want something like this:

```
which("B" %in% aList[names(aList)]) # It would be nice if this returned v1 and v2
which("E" %in% aList[names(aList)]) # It would be nice if this returned v1
which("C" %in% aList[names(aList)]) # It would be nice if this returned v2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
names(aList)[sapply(1:2,function(x){"B" %in% aList[[x]]})]
[1] "v1" "v2" 

names(aList)[sapply(1:2,function(x){"E" %in% aList[[x]]})]
[1] "v1"

names(aList)[sapply(1:2,function(x){"C" %in% aList[[x]]})]
[1] "v2"
```

If you have a list with an unknown numbers of element, use `seq_along` :

```
names(aList)[sapply(seq_along(aList),function(x){"B" %in% aList[[x]]})]
[1] "v1" "v2"
```

Here is a microbenchmark regarding the comments.

```
microbenchmark(seq_along(aList),seq_along(names(aList)),1:length(aList),times=100000)
Unit: nanoseconds
                    expr min  lq     mean median   uq    max neval cld
        seq_along(aList) 350 700 659.9117    701  701 208228 1e+05 a  
 seq_along(names(aList)) 351 701 857.1508    701 1051 216977 1e+05  b 
         1:length(aList) 700 701 935.7251   1050 1051 424855 1e+05   c

microbenchmark(etienne(),roland())
Unit: microseconds
      expr    min     lq     mean median     uq     max neval cld
 etienne() 40.597 41.297 45.24751 41.646 41.997 211.378   100   b
  roland() 12.600 13.300 14.40882 14.699 15.049  20.998   100  a
```

Comment: I'd prefer `names(aList)[vapply(aList, is.element, el = "B", FUN.VALUE = FALSE)]`.

Comment: why not just 1:length(aList) instead of seq_along?

Comment: both work fine and the microbenchmark doesn't really make a difference. But Roland's answer is three times faster as mine

Comment: @panterasBox `seq_along` is safer. Compare `seq_along(NULL)` with `1:length(NULL)`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing this individually, we can use `outer` with `%in%` to get the logical matrix ('m1'), `split` it by `row` and get the corresponding `names` of 'aList'.

```
v1 <- c('B', 'E', 'C')
m1 <- outer(v1, aList, FUN= Vectorize(`%in%`))
lapply(split(m1, row(m1)), function(x) names(aList)[x])
# $`1`
#[1] "v1" "v2"

#$`2`
#[1] "v1"

#$`3`
#[1] "v2"
```

Or we `melt` the 'm1' and `split` by 'long' format column.

```
library(reshape2)
with(melt(m1), split(as.character(Var2[value]), Var1[value]))
```